# Why is EmberData sends request for 'models/?model_id'

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

With an Ember Model call Itinerary EmberData is rightly requesting 'http://localhost.dev/itinenaries' for App.Itinerary.find()

However when EmberData requesting a single model the request looks like this 'http://localhost.dev/itineraries?itinerary_id=2' for App.Itinerary.find(1)

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kiwiupover/km2T4/2/)

```
App = Ember.Application.create()

App.Itinerary = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr 'string'
  description: DS.attr 'string'

App.ItineraryRoute = Em.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    App.Itinerary.find(params)

App.Store = DS.Store.extend()

DS.RESTAdapter.configure 'plurals',
  itinerary: 'itineraries'

App.Router.map ->
    @resource 'itineraries', ->
        @resource 'itinerary', path: '/:itinerary_id', ->
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the route I never gave an id to the params.

It should have look like this.

```
App.ItineraryRoute = Em.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    App.Itinerary.find(params.itinerary_id)
```